# C++ Setting the larger of two variables to a new value

Tags: c++, algorithm, max

If I have two variables, `a` and `b`, `std::max(a,b)` returns the higher value.

Is it somehow possible to have this function *modify* whichever variable turns out to be greater, i.e. if `x` is a third variable,

```
max(a,b) = x;
```

such that after this call `a==x` holds if `a` was greater than `b`, else `b==x`?

Comment: You want to return the maximum value from the function ?

Comment: What should happen if `a` and `b` have equal values? Should both be set to the value of `x`?

Comment: What's wrong with an if-statement?

Comment: @BoPersson Nothing, I just wondered whether is it possible.

Comment: @gen: I can think of two ways to do it easily

Comment: @MooingDuck Looking forward to hearing from them

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
int &max(int &a, int &b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Then:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 10, y = 20;
    max(x, y) = 100;
}
```

`max` will return a reference to the maximum number, then you can put your `max` function in the left hand of the assignment and change its value.

Template based version:

```
template<typename T>
T &max(T &a, T &b)
{
  return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: This one is sane. A lot better than the macro solution anyway.

Comment: just maybe give it another name, not to mix with the standard max

Comment: @nogard Standard `max` is actually `std::max`, so there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: @Angew Unless people write `using namespace std;` which of course nobody does... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create such function :

```
template< typename T >
T& AssignableMax( T& a, T& b )
{
  return ( a > b ) ? a : b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using references:

```
int& maxref(int& a, int& b)
{
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
maxref(a, b) = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a macro if that is acceptable to you (just avoid giving it the name of a standard algorithm such as `max`):

```
#define mmax(x, y) ((x > y) ? (x) : (y))

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    mmax(x, y) = 2;
}
```

If you do not want to use macros, here is a generic solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
T& mmax(T& t, T& u)
{ return (t < u) ? u : t; }

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    mmax(x, y) = 2;

    std::cout << x << y;
}
```